# After doing some git operations, I end up with multiple files duplicates on my finder

Tags: git, icloud

I just did a rebase on my project and a lot of files were duplicated.

[image]

This happened right after I did a rebase onto the develop branch.

Deleting the files do no harm to the project, but I want to know what is causing this problem so I can fix it.

Comment: This is almost certainly not caused by git but by some regular finder copy operations you performed.

Comment: git doesn't duplicate files like this. Something else is doing this

Comment: Maybe it's some weird interaction with iCloud services. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Is the code inside a cloud backup folder, like iCloud or Dropbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not store your Git repository in iCloud Drive or any other sync service.

Git makes lots of changes to files very quickly and iCloud might not keep up. For example, a rebase can change hundreds of files hundreds of times in a few seconds. iCloud doesn’t want you to lose data, so it will err on the side of caution.

Since you’re not editing the files interactively, it doesn’t have a chance to give you a conflict resolution GUI, so it will default to keep both, and increment a number.