# Project duplicate files

Tags: xcode, git

I noticed that my project folder start to contain duplication of files for example, I have some view controller and its modules, so I will have viewcontrolller file and view controller2 file. Why can it be?

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with git itself. If these duplicate files are *versioned in git* check who committed and shared them in the first place. You will have to look for the reason why `<file>2.swift` exists in the first place elsewhere (accidental click&drag ? download a file from your browser ? ...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After doing some git operations, I end up with multiple files duplicates on my finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358051/after-doing-some-git-operations-i-end-up-with-multiple-files-duplicates-on-my-f)